# Installing Julia 0.6.4 on Catalina Machine

Tags: julia, macos-catalina

Done this multiple times before on Windows machines with no issues. But after installing Julia Pro on a Catalina machine, I keep getting this error when I try to add the Gurobi package with  Pkg.add("Gurobi"):

ERROR: SystemError: realpath: No such file or directory

I tried giving Julia full disk access per the only comment I have seen elsewhere. I have also defined the path to Gurobi correctly I believe with ENV["GUROBI_HOME"] = "/Library/gurobi811/mac64"

Anything else I can do? This is older code so was hoping to avoid updating it to work with Julia 1.x.

Thank you! I have burned two days trying to figure this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only become commonplace recently for packages to put upper-bounds on the version of Julia itself or their dependencies; indeed it's now a requirement for registering new versions automatically. But in the old days we were much looser about that. As a consequence, there may be versions of Gurobi that claim to work with a wider variety of Julia versions than they really do, or packages that work together in certain versions but not in others, without any way for `Pkg` to know what the magic combinations are.

You may need to manually install a version of Gurobi that was "modern" at the time of Julia 0.6. But you should also expect to have to do this kind of digging for other packages that you will use.

Given how much time you've spent on this, I think your better option is to install Julia 0.7 and use its warnings to tell you how to modernize your code. Once done, you can use Julia 1.x. But it's much easier to get to 1.x through 0.7 than it is to jump straight to 1.x.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That’s sort of what I expected. I just got started and it seems pretty painful to edit so many lines of constraints and variables, which brings me to a follow up: is there any sort of syntax change catalog to reference? Otherwise this might be a real slog...thanks again!

Comment: Anything regarding Julia should be covered by the deprecation warnings that you're given by Julia 0.7. For JuMP I am less sure, but http://www.juliaopt.org/JuMP.jl/v0.20.0/ links to the NEWS.md file, which should be helpful.